# Mod Tiles configuring probelem

Tags: mapnik

I have installed all most every requirements to configure Mod Tiles. When I am trying to install it by ./autogen.sh its not installing. Its replying

```
./autogen.sh: 2: ./autogen.sh: autoreconf: not found
```

Can any body tell me whats happen?

Comment: Please add your output. What do you mean by not installing?

Comment: I have edited my question